# Power MOSFET protection from inductive loads

Tags: mosfet, snubber, avalanche-breakdown

I have a circuit which is a low side switch for a BMS. And because this a power board that is separate from the actual BMS, I don't the access to Batt+ line. (The Batt+ line is directly given to the load terminal from the top cell.) I am looking for a way to have some component/circuitry between the drain and source of the MOSFET to protect the MOSFET during turn off.

During turn off, I want to protect the Drain-Source of MOSFET from exceeding the maximum Vds voltage. The power lines cables (Batt+ and Batt-) are very long and this is where most of the inductance is coming from.

MOSFET MPN: BSC061N08NS5ATMA1 ([Link to Digikey Page](https://www.digikey.in/en/products/detail/infineon-technologies/BSC061N08NS5ATMA1/5959906))

Here are the things I've considered but having doubts:

1. **RCD Snubber**: I am having issues with this because most resources I find online in order to calculate the values needs the switching frequency, which is 0 I think in this case because we just turn the MOSFET off which a protection gets triggered and we are not switching per se and some other frequencies which I cannot measure now. ([Link to calculation I am referring to from TI](https://www.ti.com/document-viewer/lit/html/SSZTBC7))
2. A **TVS diode between Drain and Source** of the MOSFET: The problem with this is the MOSFET used has a max Vds of 80V and the max working voltage of my system is 58V. So I need a TVS with working voltage higher than 58V and a clamping voltage of less than 80V. A TVS with this spec is just not available.
3. Using a **Zener between Drain and Source** that has a Vz of ~75V: While there are Zeners available with this spec, I am not sure if the Zeners can actually dissipate the power.

Few other things I am reading about while I am writing this post:

a) Avalanche diodes: BYG20J-E3/TR

b) Surface-Mount Glass Passivated Rectifier: S8KS-E3/I

Please share your thoughts.

Edit: Schematic snippet attached.
[image: Sch]

Comment: A schematic would save us from trying to interpret the text, which I am struggling to do.  How often would this MOSFET be switching on and off?

Comment: Please add the maximum wire length or supply inductance your circuit is expected to operate with, peak load current at turn-off, and any other extenuating circumstances (for example, why can a bypass capacitor not be connected at the load+switch? Is the MOSFET a requirement or can it change?) What are the load characteristics, is inrush current or energy any concern?

Comment: @FabioBarone Ideally the MOSFET will never turn off. It will turn off only when a protection is triggered. So basically few to none.

Comment: 1. Please update your schematic to show how it connects to: (a) battery, (b) charger, (c) load. (d) gate drivers for the MOSFETs   2.   Node [DSG_G].  Is shown connected to D2 cathode AND to C3 cathode (=Q9 emitter), is that correct?

Comment: @FabioBarone This is board is on the negative line on the battery. This board is basically a switch sitting in between the cathode of the Cell 1 in the stack and the load/charger terminal. Gate driver on a different board it is taken care of. 2) Yes, it is connected that way. Its a local current loop help the stray capacitance in the discharge MOSFET to drain faster aiding in the turn off time. I'm simply looking for solutions to protect my drain and source from inductive switch off.